# Reformat CloudWatch logs sent to S3 using Kinesis Firehose for JSON

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a working setup that sends CloudWatch logs to a S3 bucket using Kinesis Firehose.  Unfortunately the files in S3 do not contain properly formatted JSON.  A properly formatted array of JSON objects will look like this: [{}, {}, {}].  However, the S3 files created by Firehose look like this: {}{}{}.  I am attempting to modify a Kinesis Firehose Data Transform Lambda Blueprint by adding the square brackets at beginning and end and commas between the JSON objects.  The Lambda Blue print I am attempting to modify is called "Process CloudWatch logs sent to Kinesis Firehose".  Here are the relevant parts:

```
import base64
import json
import gzip
import boto3


def transformLogEvent(log_event):
    """Transform each log event.

    The default implementation below just extracts the message and appends a newline to it.

    Args:
    log_event (dict): The original log event. Structure is {"id": str, "timestamp": long, "message": str}

    Returns:
    str: The transformed log event.
    """
    return log_event['message'] + ',\n'


def processRecords(records):
    for r in records:
        data = loadJsonGzipBase64(r['data'])
        recId = r['recordId']
        # CONTROL_MESSAGE are sent by CWL to check if the subscription is reachable.
        # They do not contain actual data.
        if data['messageType'] == 'CONTROL_MESSAGE':
            yield {
                'result': 'Dropped',
                'recordId': recId
            }
        elif data['messageType'] == 'DATA_MESSAGE':
            joinedData = ''.join([transformLogEvent(e) for e in data['logEvents']])
            dataBytes = joinedData.encode("utf-8")
            encodedData = base64.b64encode(dataBytes).decode('utf-8')
            yield {
                'data': encodedData,
                'result': 'Ok',
                'recordId': recId
            }
        else:
            yield {
                'result': 'ProcessingFailed',
                'recordId': recId
            }

def loadJsonGzipBase64(base64Data):
    return json.loads(gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(base64Data)))


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    isSas = 'sourceKinesisStreamArn' in event
    streamARN = event['sourceKinesisStreamArn'] if isSas else event['deliveryStreamArn']
    region = streamARN.split(':')[3]
    streamName = streamARN.split('/')[1]
    records = list(processRecords(event['records']))
    projectedSize = 0
    recordListsToReingest = []

    for idx, rec in enumerate(records):
        originalRecord = event['records'][idx]

        if rec['result'] != 'Ok':
            continue

        # If a single record is too large after processing, split the original CWL data into two, each containing half
        # the log events, and re-ingest both of them (note that it is the original data that is re-ingested, not the 
        # processed data). If it's not possible to split because there is only one log event, then mark the record as
        # ProcessingFailed, which sends it to error output.
        if len(rec['data']) > 6000000:
            cwlRecord = loadJsonGzipBase64(originalRecord['data'])
            if len(cwlRecord['logEvents']) > 1:
                rec['result'] = 'Dropped'
                recordListsToReingest.append(
                    [createReingestionRecord(isSas, originalRecord, data) for data in splitCWLRecord(cwlRecord)])
            else:
                rec['result'] = 'ProcessingFailed'
                print(('Record %s contains only one log event but is still too large after processing (%d bytes), ' +
                    'marking it as %s') % (rec['recordId'], len(rec['data']), rec['result']))
            del rec['data']
        else:
            projectedSize += len(rec['data']) + len(rec['recordId'])
            # 6000000 instead of 6291456 to leave ample headroom for the stuff we didn't account for
            if projectedSize > 6000000:
                recordListsToReingest.append([createReingestionRecord(isSas, originalRecord)])
                del rec['data']
                rec['result'] = 'Dropped'

    # call putRecordBatch/putRecords for each group of up to 500 records to be re-ingested
    if recordListsToReingest:
        recordsReingestedSoFar = 0
        client = boto3.client('kinesis' if isSas else 'firehose', region_name=region)
        maxBatchSize = 500
        flattenedList = [r for sublist in recordListsToReingest for r in sublist]
        for i in range(0, len(flattenedList), maxBatchSize):
            recordBatch = flattenedList[i:i + maxBatchSize]
            # last argument is maxAttempts
            args = [streamName, recordBatch, client, 0, 20]
            if isSas:
                putRecordsToKinesisStream(*args)
            else:
                putRecordsToFirehoseStream(*args)
            recordsReingestedSoFar += len(recordBatch)
            print('Reingested %d/%d' % (recordsReingestedSoFar, len(flattenedList)))

    print('%d input records, %d returned as Ok or ProcessingFailed, %d split and re-ingested, %d re-ingested as-is' % (
        len(event['records']),
        len([r for r in records if r['result'] != 'Dropped']),
        len([l for l in recordListsToReingest if len(l) > 1]),
        len([l for l in recordListsToReingest if len(l) == 1])))
    
    # encapsulate in square brackets for proper JSON formatting
    last = len(event['records'])-1
    start = '['+base64.b64decode(records[0]['data']).decode('utf-8')
    end = base64.b64decode(records[last]['data']).decode('utf-8')+']'
    
    records[0]['data'] = base64.b64encode(start.encode('utf-8'))
    records[last]['data'] = base64.b64encode(end.encode('utf-8'))

    return {'records': records}
```

}

I added the comma before the \n in the transformLogEvent method and these lines at the end of the lambda_handler method to add the square brackets:

```
last = len(event['records'])-1
start = '['+base64.b64decode(records[0]['data']).decode('utf-8')
end = base64.b64decode(records[last]['data']).decode('utf-8')+']'
    
records[0]['data'] = base64.b64encode(start.encode('utf-8'))
records[last]['data'] = base64.b64encode(end.encode('utf-8'))
```

I am getting this error when testing this Lambda function:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'data'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "requestId": "04ac151c-c429-484d-813f-ffd5d65286e2",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 270, in lambda_handler\n    start = '['+base64.b64decode(records[0]['data']).decode('utf-8')\n"
  ]
}
```

I think this is an error in how I am referencing the Python List.  I would like to know how to fix this error and/or if someone has a better solution on how to solve the JSON format problem keeping in mind that CloudWatch Logs events are sent to Kinesis Data Firehose in compressed gzip format.

Answer (score 1):

It is failing because your "processReocrds()" function can return a "record" that doesn't have a 'data' key. Specifically, if the input record is a CONTROL_MESSAGE, or if it isn't a CONTORL_MESSAGE nor a DATA_MESSAGE record, then the function "yields" a "dictionary" that doesn't have a 'data' key. If that is the case for the first or last record (the first one in this case) it will cause the python script to throw the exception you received.

Comment: Thanks, would you have a suggestion on how to add a leading and trailing square bracket for proper JSON formatting?

Comment: Off the top of my head, why don't you just modify the processRecords() function to have a "data' field, but set it to an empty string?

Comment: Looking further into this, you're also going to have a problem with the last record having a ',' at the end, which won't be valid JSON format. Looking at the incoming event, it can be multiple 'records', and each record will have a 'data' key and it will have multiple 'logEvents' and each logEvent will have a 'message' within it. I would recommend not trying to the modify the messages until you have flushed out the 'records' array you are building. Then, modify the first record with a '[' + <message> + ',\n' and the last record with <message> + ']', and all the others with ',\n'.